# How do I handle forfeited dependent care FSA money on my taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, fsa

I forfeited $1300 in dependent care FSA (missed deadline).  I spent $3800 total on daycare expenses.  $1300 showed up on my W2 form.  I use Turbotax. Do I need to do anything different on my tax forms since I did not get reimbursed for the $1300?  Can I claim credit for the difference of $2500?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to report the amount you forfeited on [Form 2441](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i2441.pdf):

> Under your employer's dependent care plan, you chose to have your employer set aside $5,000 to cover your 2018 dependent care expenses. The $5,000 is shown on your Form W-2, in box 10. In 2018, you incurred and were reimbursed for $4,950 of qualified
> expenses. You would enter $5,000 on line 12 and $50, the amount forfeited, on line 14.

It is up to your employer what to do with the forfeited amount:

> The IRS gives employers the following options for unused employee FSA balances that are forfeited under the use-it-or-lose-it rule. The source for this is Treasury Proposed Regulation 1.125-5(o).
>
> The employer can simply keep the money.
>
> If the employer doesn't keep the money, forfeited amounts must be used for the following purposes:
>
> To defray expenses of administering the cafeteria benefit plan under which the FSA program or programs are offered
>
> To reduce employee FSA salary reduction amounts (or employee contributions) for the immediately following FSA plan year on a reasonable and uniform basis
>
> Return them to employees on a reasonable and uniform basis

**References**

- [What Can Employers Do with Forfeited Employee FSA Balances? | Gelman, Rosenberg & Freedman, CPAs](https://www.grfcpa.com/resource/forfeited-fsa-balances/)
- [Internal Revenue Bulletin: 2007-39 | Internal Revenue Service](https://www.irs.gov/irb/2007-39_IRB)
- [Publication 907 - Tax Highlights for Persons With Disabilities - Tax Highlights for Persons With Disabilities](https://taxmap.irs.gov/taxmap/pubs/p907-000.htm)
- [Employer FSA Administrative Guide (pdf)](https://www.flexbank.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/FSAPlanAdministrationGuide.pdf)
- [Publication 907 (2017), Tax Highlights for Persons With Disabilities | Internal Revenue Service](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p907)